# How to sum rows that have the same value in a specific column

Tags: sql, sum, amazon-redshift

I am trying to get a result that displays the revenue generated by a placement. To calculate placement revenue I need to do this calculation (campaign_cpc (in €)*clicks generated by the placement). One placement can generate clicks with different campaign_cpc.

Right now the results that I am getting are like this:

```
+------------------+---------------------+
| placement_name   | placement_revenue_€ |
+------------------+---------------------+
| placement_name_1 | 147,2               |
+------------------+---------------------+
| placement_name_1 | 170,95              |
+------------------+---------------------+
| placement_name_2 | 14,4                |
+------------------+---------------------+
| placement_name_2 | 51,35               |
+------------------+---------------------+
```

This is because each placement (Placement 1 & 2) have generated clicks with two different campaign_cpc.

But I actually need the result aggregated by placement:

```
+------------------+---------------------+
| placement_name   | placement_revenue_€ |
+------------------+---------------------+
| placement_name_1 | 318,15              |
+------------------+---------------------+
| placement_name_2 | 65,75               |
+------------------+---------------------+
```

The query that I am using is this one:

```
SELECT
      placement_name,
      campaign_cpc*clicks as placement_revenue_€

FROM (

      SELECT
            p.name as placement_name,
            cc.cpc as campaign_cpc,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN re.event_type = 'click' 
            AND content_card_id IS NOT NULL THEN event_type END) as clicks

      FROM  raw_events re
      JOIN  app_data.placements p ON p.id=re.placement_id
      JOIN  app_data.content_cards cc ON cc.id=re.content_card_id

      GROUP BY 
          cc.cpc,
          p.name
      )

GROUP BY
      placement_name,
      clicks

ORDER BY 
      placement_name
```

How can I amend the above query to get the aggregated result?

I am using PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.1337

Many thanks!

Comment: Currently you are grouping by `click` but there is no field by this name (there is a field `clicks`). Also, a comma after `click` will make it not SQL. So something isn't accurate in the question. Basically, @JoshKopen has the correct fix, but perhaps the problem is different. Just use copy-paste, from actual output - it's faster.

Comment: @DanGetz Thank you for your answer. I just corrected the clicks thing. This is because I condensed the query manually before posting, so that it is easier to read (there are many types of click events in the original query). I am still seeing the same results. Any other ideas? Thanks again guys!

Comment: Like @JoshKopen said, remove the `clicks` from the second (outer) `GROUP BY` and add a `SUM()` around the `campaign_cpc*clicks` and it should do it. But perhaps you are uncondensing the answer and adding something.

Comment: What you guys said is actually correct. Just needed to transfer your comment correctly into the original query. Thank you very much guys, have a great weekend both! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to fix your statement to get your desired results is to not group by click as well. Only group by placement_name. This will no longer differentiate rows with different clicks so your summing will work correctly. Also put sum around clicks in your select statement.

Comment: thank you Josh for the quick answer. I just tried that but unfortunately doesn't do the trick. I still have the same result. Let me know if there is anything else that can be done. Thank you very much!

Comment: Try putting SUM around clicks for the multiplication at the top

Comment: You're getting the exact same results as before?

Comment: Yes, exact same results.

Comment: Hey @JoshKopen; you may want to update your answer so that it states: remove the `clicks` from the second (outer) `GROUP BY` and add a `SUM()` around the campaign_cpc*clicks